# Can't clone our own project from Github

Tags: github

We've previously been able to clone from Github just fine but now whenever we try it never gets beyond about 35%. This is a large repository but it's worked fine in the past. Looking at the status line the download rate starts out at a decent rate 200 - 500 KiB/s but progressively drops until it ends up at 1 - 5 Kib/S. Eventually it times out with the message:

```
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1532/1532), done.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200
```

Here's the repository and the command we're using:

```
git clone https://github.com/t2health/BSPAN---Bluetooth-Sensor-Processing-for-Android.git
```

Comment: This seems to be a question for [GitHub Support](https://help.github.com/contact)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is probably better to ask GitHub support about this.

Comment: Not really, worked here.

Answer (score 1):

Works here, so get a better internet connection.

We have 100Mb fiber to the home near Chattanooga, TN.

I used to use a cell company's wireless mifi device, and it would do what you are complaining about.  Perhaps, your connections are being throttled.

```
git clone https://github.com/t2health/BSPAN---Bluetooth-Sensor-Processing-for-Android.git
Cloning into 'BSPAN---Bluetooth-Sensor-Processing-for-Android'...
remote: Counting objects: 6127, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1532/1532), done.
remote: Total 6127 (delta 3883), reused 6117 (delta 3873)
Receiving objects: 100% (6127/6127), 87.27 MiB | 743 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3883/3883), done.
```